# Bokeh Streaming Data Into Applet

Tags: python-2.7, applet, bokeh

*Note from maintainers: This question concerns the obsolete first generation Bokeh server. For details about modern Bokeh server applications, see:*

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

---

---

***OBSOLETE:***

I'd like to integrate streaming in my applet, but I'm not sure how to do so.  I'm new to bokeh, and a relatively beginner to python.  I used the stock_app as a launching point for setting up my app.

Details: The streaming wouldn't necessarily be ultra-low interval (3-5 minutes is OK).  Streaming in bokeh seems to be generally carried out via the renderer. The idea is that the datasource is updated, and the plots, etc. then also updated.

However, this is all done through a `while` loop, whereas the bokeh applets generally follow the format of

```
class Dashboard(obj):

@bokeh_app.route('/bokeh/dashboard/')
@object_page('dashboard')
def make_object():
    return Dashboard.create()
```

If I insert a while loop, the page never loads, understandably.  I can see in the cmd that the data is being updated via logs, but the visualization is never completed.

Reading through the github repo, I've found that apart from this basic method, there is also `reload.py` in bokeh.server.utils, which provides `_wait_for_edit` and `robust_reloader`.  But again, I'm not sure how to best integrate these into the applet without completely stopping the process.  Any code examples would be greatly appreciated!